# Is that possible to remove this icon on share on Samsung? | Android 11

Tags: java, android, kotlin, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

When I tried to share some URLs (String type) via `Intent.createChooser` I got an unknown icon on Samsung S10 (Android 11). Can I remove this icon or add an Application icon?

[Share screen with icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4R8w.png)

Here is my code:

```kotlin
override fun applyShare(textRes: String) {
    val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, textRes)
        type = "text/plain"
    }
     
    val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "TITLE")
    startActivity(shareIntent)
}
```

Comment: same issues. do you have resolve this

Comment: Same here. I would like to modify it rather than delete it. Any clue?